# How do you stop Safari from offering passwords from all subdomains of a domain?

Tags: macos, safari, password, domain

So I have these few websites in the same domain (i.e. example1.domain.com and example2.domain.com) that have a different subdomain and Safari offers me passwords from all of them when I enter just one of them.

Is there a way to disable Safari offering passwords if the subdomain is different?

Comment: I have the same question, no one?

Comment: Try taking a look at your keychain. You can search for the site and see if the password is lasted as domain.com if it is you can add the appropriate sub domain to the url. Then you can duplicate it, and change the credentials for the other sub domains.

Comment: just a guess but I'd suspect most browsers use the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/) to decide whether or not to treat subdomains as different websites

Answer (score 3):

As of February 2021: No

However this could be a good option and I suggest to everyone to voice your opinion [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. You can manually add one password for "example1.domain.com" and another for "example2.domain.com" by clicking the plus button under **Preferences** > **Passwords**.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that as long as you use a different username/email address for your subdomain, the iCloud keychain will store separate passwords. Otherwise if the username and (sub)domains match, the last (sub)domain entry will overwrite the password entry for all related domains.